# Hear me call again, again

Tags: riddle

> I'm in some shelters or outside
>
> I do not run nor do I hide -
>
> I hear your voice and answer back,
>
> but when you sense me, I don't last
>
> -
>
> I'm  found in fashion, changed a bit
>
> but you can't see me - that's not it.
>
> So if you're listening for my name
>
> You'll hear me call again, again.

Comment: The answer to this is a nice answer for a riddle, in my opinion... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> An echo?

I'm in some shelters or outside

I do not run nor do I hide -

> Echos can be heard in caves (a type of shelter) or in mountains. It can't run or hide, because it's not physically real.

I hear your voice and answer back,

but when you sense me, I don't last

> Echos answer your voice but fade away.

I'm found in fashion, changed a bit

but you can't see me - that's not it.

> Fashions echo each other in history.

So if you're listening for my name

You'll hear me call again, again.

> Perhaps this refers to when you shout "Echo", it shouts it back to you again and again.

Comment: I tried to make it hard, but I knew it would be solved pretty quickly. Way to jump on that right away!

Comment: Your answer is right, but the last two reasons are slightly off from what I was thinking, specifically the last one